# Is there a way to check which system was used to send mail?

Tags: emails, 9

Is there a way to check which system was used to send mail?

I followed [Sending html mails in Drupal 8/9 programmatically](https://www.lucius.digital/en/blog/sending-html-mails-drupal-89-programmatically-example-drupal-module-including-twig-template). I'm using the SMTP module to make sure that emails are sent via SMTP instead of using the PHP mailer. Emails sent via my website seem to have a higher spam score than when the ones sent directly from my [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) server. I wonder whether my mails are being sent via SMTP or not.

Is there a method to check this?

Answer (score -1):

**A way to check is using Gmail.**

Sometimes it's obvious:

[image]

But most aren't, so you can click on the 3 dots and select show original

[image]

Here, for example, you can see this other one was sent using Zoho Mail's SMTP

[image]

---

By the way, I was also seeing emails sometimes land in the spam box using SMTP. Once I setup SPF, DKIM, and DMARC for my domain, I've never seen them land in spam again.

> There are three main types of authentication used
> to prove to mailbox providers that your email is worth being placed in
> the inbox:
>
> **SPF (Sender Policy Framework)** is an IP address-based authentication method used to compare the sender’s IP indicated in the
> domain’s DNS record with a list of IPs authorized to send from that
> domain.
>
> **DKIM (Domain Keys Identified Mail)** is a method for validating domains
> through a publicly available cryptographic signature. This signature
> is verified on the receiving end using the DNS record.
>
> **DMARC (Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance)** is a protocol aimed at reducing email phishing and
> spoofing. It allows a sender to specify that their email is properly
> authenticated using DKIM and SPF records.
>
> **Senders who authenticate their messages with all three methods may see
> less filtering and fewer emails going to spam.**
>
> <sub>source: [How to Prevent Emails from Going to Spam: The Ultimate Guide](https://sendpulse.com/blog/prevent-emails-landing-spam-folder)</sub>

Comment: Ah I see, showing the original shows me the following: Using PHPMailer 6.5.4 so I guess the SMTP module is not used. How can I force my code to use the SMTP module?

Comment: @Joost install the [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module and in its configuration `/admin/config/system/mailsystem` for "sender" select SMTP.

Comment: I'm using mailsystem and just changed everything to SMTP. In the top it still says:
`From: # Using PHPMailer 6.6.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)`
But in the code part you are mentioning it says:
`Received: from # by mx.google.com with SMTP`
So I think it works? Right? I tried sending via Google Workspace.